# Flutter: Is There a Performance Penalty for a Single Global Widget Import?

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter and have created a bunch of UI elements as custom widgets so that I can use them throughout my app. It's tiresome to have to remember to include each and every widget `import` in a Dart file.

I recently learned that you can export a widget from within another widget, and anything that imports the parent widget has access to everything:

```dart
//===================
//=== global.dart ===
//===================

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myapp/storage.dart';

//Widget exports for convenience
export 'package:myapp/_global/widgets/widget1.dart';
export 'package:myapp/_global/widgets/widget2.dart';
export 'package:myapp/_global/widgets/widget3.dart';
```

So now in each of my files throughout my project, I just need to do:

```
import 'package:myapp/global.dart';
```

...and I have access to `widget1`, `widget2`, `widget3`.

Is there a risk to doing this, such as a performance decrease or something else I can't foresee? It's awfully convenient for development. I'm just trying to make sure I'm not shooting myself in the foot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of file exporting is called "barrel" exporting. There's an extension for both [Visual Studio Code Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=miquelddg.dart-barrel-file-generator) and [Android Studio extension](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18980-dart-barrel-file-generator) that does this automatically for you!

> Is there a risk to doing this, such as a performance decrease or something else I can't foresee?

I don't think there's a risk, though I don't know. I have taken a Flutter course from an expert who recommends doing barrel import. And actually, if you look at the source code for some Flutter packages, you'll see that that's *exactly* what they do.

For example, take a look at the most used import of `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';`, you'll see that they use barrel importing:

```dart
...
library material;

export 'src/material/about.dart';
export 'src/material/animated_icons.dart';
export 'src/material/app.dart';
export 'src/material/app_bar.dart';
export 'src/material/app_bar_theme.dart';
export 'src/material/arc.dart';
export 'src/material/autocomplete.dart';
export 'src/material/back_button.dart';
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! This is super convenient.