# Can reference another pubspec.yaml in my pubspec.yaml?

Tags: flutter, dart

Can I have my pubspec.yaml use another like a base for the dependencies

to be used in my package?

So pubspec.yaml that can reference another as its base?

Comment: Maybe just create a package that exports other packages?

Comment: I have multiple packages, but want for all of them to have same dart and flutter dependencies (for example). Would rather to write it once, and have it shared across all of them. Is there a way?

Comment: @o_w I'm not sure if this is what you want. But you might want to look at barrel files: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76880237/12349734

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is for those packages to use the same dependencies, then maybe you could just create a new package where it stores all the needed packages, then create a library. You create a new dart file and paste something like this:

```
library my_library
export 'package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter/ffmpeg_kit.dart';
```

Then for every of the projects which needed all of those packages can just add this new package and import the library file.

So if you for example wanted to add a new dependency to this new exporting package, you can just add it then export it. If you published this exporting package to `pub.dev` you may need to update the version in each of the pubspec.yaml of the projects using the package by just changing the version number and running `pub get`, however it will be less of a hassle compared to adding the dependencies manually.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Does this option mean we can include in the proposed package dart and flutter version and exclude them from every other pubspec using it, for example?

Comment: I don't entirely understand what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I have several package nested under one folder, each has its own pubspec. Since I want them all to be based on the same Dart and Flutter version, I thought maybe there's a way to make a "base" pubspec for them all to use while still allowing each of them to expand upon its declared dependencies.

Comment: A base pubspec would require a base Flutter package where it stores all the dependencies in the pubspec and export files so any projects depending on this base Flutter package would be able to import the exported files. However, if you make a change in the base Flutter package, and for example increased the version and uploaded it to pub.dev as a new version, then these projects depending on the base would need to be updated each. You can do that by running pub get.

Comment: It seemed to me you are skeptical of creating a base package. After a bit of search, I found a tool called shared_versions. Maybe it can help you out. https://github.com/littleGnAl/shared_versions

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn't be considered a good practice. When you add a dependency (lets call it "Package A") to your project, it becomes a direct dependency, while any of the dependencies of "Package A" become [*transitive* dependencies](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/glossary#transitive-dependency).

As far as how the two types of dependencies are handled/tree shaken, I don't know how they differ, but they have specific naming for them ‍♂️

There is a lint that discourages this type of behavior as well, [`depend_on_referenced_packages`](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/depend_on_referenced_packages). Here is states

> Depending explicitly on packages that you reference *ensures they will always exist* ...

This implies that the dependency could **not** exist at some point in the future. Probably if some OS maintainer removed a package that they no longer used within their project.

Now, if you're the maintainer of said package, I am sure that you'll know whether a dependency has been removed, so this will likely not be an issue.

Ultimately, its up to you, just know that its better practice to explicitly depend on packages that you're using within your project.

---

If you wanted to achieve a "base pubspec.yaml", here is how you could do it:

- you'd need to create the base project

  ```
    .
    ├── base_pkg
    │   ├── lib
    │   │   └── base_pkg.dart
    │   └── pubspec.yaml
    └── working_project
        ├── ...
        └── pubspec.yaml
  ```
- add the dependencies to the pubspec.yaml

  ```yaml
  # (base_pkg) pubspec.yaml
  name: base_pkg

  dependencies:
     json_annotation: ...
  ```
- export the dependencies from the project's src file

  ```dart
  // lib/base_pkg.dart

  export 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
  ```
- add the base project to your working project (via path)

  ```yaml
  # (project) pubspec.yaml

  dependencies:
     base_pkg:
       path: ../base_pkg # absolute/relative path to base_pkg
  ```
- use the base_pkg's dependencies within your project

  ```dart
  import 'package:base_pkg/base_pkg.dart';

  @JsonSerializable()
  class SomeClass {
      ...
  }
  ```

**Note:**
This approach will only work with `dependencies` not `dev_dependencies`. All [`dev_dependencies`](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dev-dependencies) are only used within the project that imports them, so you would need to re-add them to your working project.

> Dev dependencies differ from regular dependencies in that *dev dependencies of packages you depend on are ignored*.

Comment: I don't know if I want another package honestly, is there no way to just export an existing pubspec for use in another as a link/reference?

Comment: No, there is not a way to do that. This is how dart handles project setup/dependency configuration, as of right now, there is not an OOB way to merge/reference pubspecs.